# numerical analysis of partial integro-differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, integral-equations, integro-differential-equations

I have to numerically solve a nonlinear partial integro-differential equation. This is my equation,

$$\frac{\partial y(x,t)}{\partial t}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty K_0(|x-u|) \frac{\partial^2 y(u,t)}{\partial u^2}\mathrm du-\sin\,y(x,t)$$

The kernel $K$ is the modified Bessel function of the 2nd kind which has a logarithmic singularity at zero and decays as exponential (logarithmic singularities are integrable) and answer $y$ is a function of $x,t$.

Notice, the derivative inside the integral is a second derivation in spacial component and the equation has a non-linearity of $sin(y(x,t))$.
Does this equation belong to any special class of integral equations? (Fredholm, Volterra ...)
Please experts who have some experience with numerical recipes dealing with integral equations reply.

Comment: I'm no expert on this class of equations, but I would ask you whether you expect in advance that the solution is stable.

Comment: Yes, This equation describes a physical phenomenon which has been simplified for the sake of argument.

Comment: Do you have a (or some) particular numerical method in mind? What are the boundary conditions? (I assume this is an initial value problem and $y$ decays to zero at infinity). How do you need the solution parameterized?

Comment: Well, this is an integral equation which all boundary conditions are represented using that kernel, so to be solved it does not need any boundary condition, but yes! the solution would change from zero to 2$Pi$ in (-$infinty$ $infinity$)

Comment: I honestly wrote down a code using method of lines which is simply defining a mesh of spacial points over a bounded space which I am more interested (say N points), thus I will get N coupled ODEs which can be solved by ODE solvers in MATLAB, but I do not trust this and it does take a long time due to the singularity. I will give you more info if you ask.

Comment: Well, your kernel has infinite support, so $y$ has infinite spatial support. When you want to solve this numerically, you need to choose a set of basis functions with which to represent $y$ in space. How do you propose to do that? Are you also given $y(x,0)$ for all $x$? And in what format is that information? Is it a specific closed form, or is it numerical data with finite spatial support?

Comment: I do have to give an initial condition $y(x,0)$ and it can be a simple kink in space in the form of $4ArcTan(exp(x))$.

Comment: Ok.... well, that initial condition has infinite support, but I see that the nonlinear term is still compact. Instead of method of lines, I would try using spatial finite elements (triangle hat functions) allowing you to pre-integrate the kernel against the hat basis functions. You should get a time invariant Toeplitz matrix for the integral operator part.

Comment: @VictorLiu 
I would try that, but could you please more specific what should I do or read in order to familiarize my self with that method? does my equation belong to a specific class of integral equations?